# c - Read data, that is written to one char device, by other char devices of the same driver

Tags: c, linux, driver

I have a task to create a driver for char devices, in which data, which is written into one char device, can be read by other devices. I know how to create multiple devices within one driver and how to read/write from/to them, but i can't find a solution to "read from one by others". Is this possible ?

Comment: code ?? where is your code ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know , a device file is pipe. So there should be one reader and writer. In your example you want writer write on pipe1 and reader on pipe2 read what was written in pipe1. It is not possible in kernel module by opening single device. If you want it you have to open two device and then it is possible.